# How to reduce mysql memory used

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.1 and want to upgrade to latest version 5.6.17 (from [Windows Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/))

But when I installed, it used too much memory, about 420Mb although 5.1 vesion run only 8Mb memory. The setup type I choose:

- Setup Type: Server Only
- Config Type: Development Machine

I don't want it uses too much memory, how can I do, or what is lastest version of MySQL that use minimum memory like 5.1

I change config type to another type but It still uses than 400Mb ram

Comment: Can you paste the result of : show variables like "%buffer%";

Answer (score 7):

I have an article on this here: http://www.tocker.ca/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html:

> The MySQL defaults have to balance performance with what is considered reasonable for what may be a development system with other applications needing to run alongside MySQL. In many cases, this will mean 4-8GB, but on virtual machines (or in my case with 7 copies of mysqld running), there is a lot less available.
>
> **Obligatory warning**: If you are running these settings on a machine with 1GB+ RAM, you should expect worse performance when compared to the defaults.
>
> ```
> Setting                     Default      Minimum
> innodb_buffer_pool_size     128M         5M
> innodb_log_buffer_size      1M           256K
> query_cache_size            1M           0
> max_connections             151          1 (although 10 might be more reasonable)
> key_buffer_size             8388608      8
> thread_cache_size           (autosized)  0
> host_cache_size             (autosized)  0
> innodb_ft_cache_size        8000000      1600000
> innodb_ft_total_cache_size  640000000    32000000
> thread_stack    262144      131072
> sort_buffer_size            262144       32K
> read_buffer_size            131072       8200
> read_rnd_buffer_size        262144       8200
> max_heap_table_size         16777216     16K
> tmp_table_size  16777216    1K
> bulk_insert_buffer_size     8388608      0
> join_buffer_size            262144       128
> net_buffer_length           16384        1K
> innodb_sort_buffer_size     1M           64K
> binlog_cache_size           32K          4K
> binlog_stmt_cache_size      32K          4K
> ```
>
> To summarize these changes:
>
> ```
> # /etc/my.cnf:
> innodb_buffer_pool_size=5M
> innodb_log_buffer_size=256K
> query_cache_size=0
> max_connections=10
> key_buffer_size=8
> thread_cache_size=0
> host_cache_size=0
> innodb_ft_cache_size=1600000
> innodb_ft_total_cache_size=32000000
>
> # per thread or per operation settings
> thread_stack=131072
> sort_buffer_size=32K
> read_buffer_size=8200
> read_rnd_buffer_size=8200
> max_heap_table_size=16K
> tmp_table_size=1K
> bulk_insert_buffer_size=0
> join_buffer_size=128
> net_buffer_length=1K
> innodb_sort_buffer_size=64K
>
> #settings that relate to the binary log (if enabled)
> binlog_cache_size=4K
> binlog_stmt_cache_size=4K
> ```

Comment: Attempting to visit the link results in *"Oops! That page can’t be found."*

Comment: @jww Here's the new link: http://www.tocker.ca/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html

Answer (score 3):

Can you paste the result of

```
show variables like "%size%";
show variables like "%buffer%";
show variables like "%cache%";
```

There is one parameter doubtful for dev server in the default "Config Type: Development Machine", it's the **table_definition_cache**.

I'm sure that yours is set to 1400 no?

Comment it on your my.ini file or just set it to its default value : 400.

The table_definition_cache parameter is an dynamic variable, so you ca set it without restart MySQL with:

```
set global table_definition_cache=400;
```

Note that if you don't have many tables you can set this lower than 400.

Max.

Comment: The `table_definition_cache` is definitely the setting that lowers RAM most after you've tweaked the other obvious settings. For me, lowering `table_definition_cache` from `1400` to `400` reduced the MySQL process RAM usage (immediately after service start) from 500MB to 125MB.